# How to catch up viewed person in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created homework mobile application for school. I need to know who and all viewed the homework sent by the school and viewed person name must be updated in database. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using some database for this. What you can do is create a list of all student's UserID to which the homework is sent. When a student opens the homework screen you remove his UserID from the last and mark him as seen and when there is no value left you can mark homework as seen by all.